# Just moved to another apartment. Surprised to see this damage to the wall. Maintenance from building claims its not water damage. Is it? Help!

Tags: drywall, ceiling, leak, construction

Moved into a 7 yr old apartment complex. 2nd floor of 20 floors. Bubbling of the drywall bordering the ceiling a few spots, but minorbubbling goes virually the entire lenghtog the apartment along the wall. In the bedroom there is also some places bordering the ceiling where it appears it has been filled with caulking. My first though was water damage. I complained that i'm paying to be in this fancy building and they give me a unit that is damaged. Note: the ceilings are concrete.

Maintenance says: 1) This is from the building settling. 2) Whoever addressed the issue when it appeared a long time ago didnt do a good job. 3) The discoloration of the ceiling is from th painter hitting the beige with the roller onto the white ceiling. 4) This is not water damage. Also, he used a dampness meter with me present and the bubbles came out to be 17%. The range in other areas was between 14-16%.
Are they lying to me that there was no water damage?
If there wasnt, whate else could make such bubbling of the dry wall. Also, if you look at the ceiling pic of the bedroom, you an see small black holes. Maintenance claims those are from the concrete ceiling. Not sure why it would have holes.

[image: Living room pic 1]
[image: Living room pic 2]
[image: Bedroom pic 1]
[image: Bedroom pic 2]

Comment: Looks like more of a bad drywall mud, paint job than water damage, right now.  In the past, who knows.  Most building do settle and that can cause cracks in drywall, but simple fix for a good drywaller to make look like new.

Comment: The workmanship shown is shotty. I mean, just look at that track light mounted over a pancake box, holy cow. that said, why do you care, you rent?

Answer (score 1):

Most of what you see here is 7 years of wear and tear covered up by 7 years of unskilled repair work.

The ceiling looks like it wasn't fully finished nor intended to be smooth after the slab was poured.  I've seen worse.

These defects are purely cosmetic.